# BeautifulSoup inverse selection

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to create a whitelist of allowed tags in a soup, and remove the rest (essentially whitelisting certain tags). Something like this, except working:

HTML:

```
<title>title</title>
<p>p</p>
<span>span</span>
<script>script</script>
```

Python:

```
>>> p = soup.find_all('p')
>>> span =  soup.find_all('span')
>>> title = soup.find_all('title')
>>> whitelist = p + span + title

>>> [el.extract() for el in soup.find_all() if el not in whitelist]
```

This just returns a blank soup. How can this made work?

Comment: If it's a whitelist are you sure you want `if el not in whitelist` and not `if el in whitelist`?

Comment: besides the comment above, couldn't you loop through `whitelist` since you have already done your `findall`? or is it really a blacklist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to provide a callable to `find_all` to tell it which tags to keep.

```
s = '''<title>title</title>
<p>p</p>
<span>span</span>
<script>script</script>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

keepset = {'title','p','span'}

soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name in keepset)
Out[59]: [<title>title</title>, <p>p</p>, <span>span</span>]
```

Comment: I would prefer if the contents of "script" were removed as well, is that possible with this code?

Comment: Oh, I see what you need.  (something else entirely)  See edit.